# Error while building titanium apks with 3.0.0.GA sdk using ant scripting

Tags: android, ant, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I am getting the following error while trying to make titanium build with 3.0.0.GA using ant scripting

```
[exec] [ERROR] Error(s) compiling generated Java code
[exec] [ERROR] D:\Workarea\experiment\teacher\digitallyTE\build\android\gen

\com\edurite\digiteacher\DigitallyteApplication.java:36: cannot find symbol [exec] symbol : class AssetCryptImpl [exec] location: class com.edurite.digiteacher.DigitallyteApplication [exec] KrollAssetHelper.setAssetCrypt(new AssetCryptImpl()) ; [exec] ^ [exec] Note: D:\Workarea\experiment\teacher\digitallyTE\build\android\gen\c om\edurite\digitallyTE\AssetCryptImpl.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. [exec] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. [exec] 1 error [exec]

BUILD FAILED D:\Workarea\experiment\teacher\build.xml:11: exec returned: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite a while ago that the question was asked. But I guess my findings could be interesting as a `AssetCryptImpl.java:44: error: cannot find symbol` error happened to me lastly. The AssetCryptImpl.java template is filled with some asset variables during the build (check `~/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.1.0.GA/android/cli/commands/_build.js`). This process depends at least on Linux on some system commands. Those commands failed with a Segmentation Fault during my builds. Thus the asset variables don't get rendered inside the AssetCryptImpl.java template and the Java compiler will complain about missing symbols.

Check your build output for a line like

```
[INFO] : Encrypting JavaScript files: /home/simon/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.1.0.GA/android/titanium_prep.linux64 "com.example.id" "/home/simon/test/Asdf/build/android/assets" "alloy/CFG.js" "app.js" "alloy/backbone.js" "alloy/constants.js" "alloy/controllers/BaseController.js" "alloy/controllers/index.js" "alloy/styles/index.js" "alloy/sync/localStorage.js" "alloy/sync/properties.js" "alloy/sync/sql.js" "alloy/underscore.js" "alloy/widget.js" "alloy.js" "ti.cloud/ti.cloud.js" "_app_props_.json"
```

and try to run the included command.